# Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied (localhost)

Tags: windows-7, macos, xampp

I set up one of vhosts in my local htdocs folder and put a simple .php file inside just to test if the configuration works (it did). But when I copied the files and folders from the same project from another machine (Win 7) this is what I get:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rebroregistar/index.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

I am on Mac OSX Mavericks and XAMPP 5.6.3. What's going on here and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to find the files saved on your Mac - It is looking in `/Applications`, which does not exist in a Windows environment.

If you're trying to build a website between two systems, I'd recommend choosing one as the server, and using version control like Git or SVN. This way, your project can also be migrated to the final server much easier, with less issues.